# Cannot find a jsp view when spring security is applied

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a java + spring web application and spring security 3.0 is applied to it. 
Using the security intercept url I'm trying to apply none filter to a particular view (jobs.jsp) however when I request for that url the request mapping works, but returning the view (ModelAndView as jobs.jsp) does not work.

It gives me an error saying that could not found /WEB-INF/view/jobs.jsp , however the file is right there.

I think the spring security does not allow this resource to be accessed unless authenticated?

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/static/login.html" filters="none"/>
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/static/home.html" filters="none"/>
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/home/*" filters="none"/>
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/job/all/*" filters="none"/>

 <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/*" filters="none"/>
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/js/*" filters="none"/>
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/images/*" filters="none"/>

 <security:form-login login-page ="/resources/static/login.html"
                      authentication-failure-url="/resources/static/login.html"/>    
<security:logout logout-url="/logout"
                 logout-success-url="/resources/static/home.html"/>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question - you say "however when I request for that url the request mapping works, but returning the view (ModelAndView as jobs.jsp) does not work" - what do you mean by this? Please provide the specific URL that you are requesting, and the exact message you receive (supplement with logs if necessary). Also, Spr Sec doesn't do anything with your view mappings, so make very sure your mappings work without Spring Security in the picture at all (suggestion: remove the Spr Sec filter entirely from web.xml).

Answer (score 0):

The order of intercept url's caused the problem. This one works.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/job/all/*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
```

Comment: <security:intercept-url pattern="/job/all/*" access="isAnonymous()"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />